# Transform factor columns to date columns in a R data.frame using Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

Based on this question

[How can I access the levels of the factors of a data.frame in Rcpp when it is passed as an argument from R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323398/how-can-i-access-the-levels-of-the-factors-of-a-data-frame-in-rcpp-when-it-is-pa)

I want to transform the resulting character columns to dates **using Rcpp**. This is my initial code which casts factor levels to a character column.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  col2 = c("a", "b", "c"),
  col3 = factor(
    x = c("01/01/2017 00:00:00", "01/06/2017 00:00:00", "05/01/2017 00:00:00"),
    levels = c("01/01/2017 00:00:00", "01/06/2017 00:00:00", "05/01/2017 00:00:00")
    ),
  col4 = factor(
    x = c("01/01/2018 00:00:00", "01/06/2018 00:00:00", "05/01/2018 00:00:00"),
    levels = c("01/01/2018 00:00:00", "01/06/2018 00:00:00", "05/01/2018 00:00:00")
    ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
```

Rcpp code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void GetDateFromFactorLevels(DataFrame df1) {
    CharacterVector varNames = df1.names();
    for(int i = 0; i < df1.length(); i++) {
        if(Rf_isFactor(df1[i]) == 1) {
            IntegerVector tempVec=df1[i];
            df1[i] = tempVec.attr("levels");
        }
   }
}

> GetDateFromFactorLevels(df)
> sapply(df, class)
       col1        col2        col3        col4 
  "numeric" "character" "character" "character"
> df
  col1 col2                col3                col4
1    1    a 01/01/2017 00:00:00 01/01/2018 00:00:00
2    2    b 01/06/2017 00:00:00 01/06/2018 00:00:00
3    3    c 05/01/2017 00:00:00 05/01/2018 00:00:00
```

Is it possible to do this and get something like?

```
> sapply(df, class)
       col1        col2        col3        col4 
  "numeric" "character"      "Date"      "Date"

> df
  col1 col2                col3                col4
1    1    a          2017-01-01          2018-01-01
2    2    b          2017-06-01          2018-06-01
3    3    c          2017-01-05          2018-01-05
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. As [Dirk Eddelbuettel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52759241/8386140) states, this would be much easier if you could work with DatetimeVector and convert it to a DateVector. If you really must work with factors, as a quick and dirty solution (someone else might come up with something more elegant) you can do this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void GetDateFromFactorLevels(DataFrame df1) {
    int n = df1.nrows();
    for ( int i = 0; i < df1.length(); i++ ) {
        if ( Rf_isFactor(df1[i]) == 1 ) {
            IntegerVector values = df1[i]; // Get the integer values
            CharacterVector levels = values.attr("levels"); // and the levels
            DateVector result(n); // Make an empty DateVector
            for ( int j = 0; j < n; ++j ) {
                // And for every element of the factor, look up the level
                // value corresponding to its integer value,
                // and construct a Date by turning it into an std::string
                // (and specifying the applicable date format)
                result[j] = Date(std::string(levels[values[j] - 1]), "%d/%m/%Y");
            }
            // Then just replace the df1 column with the DateVector
            df1[i] = result;
        }
    }
}
```

When called from R:

```r
Rcpp::sourceCpp("date-stuff.cpp")
df <- data.frame(
    col1 = c(1, 2, 3),
    col2 = c("a", "b", "c"),
    col3 = factor(
        x = c("01/01/2017 00:00:00", "01/06/2017 00:00:00", "05/01/2017 00:00:00"),
        levels = c("01/01/2017 00:00:00", "01/06/2017 00:00:00", "05/01/2017 00:00:00")
    ),
    col4 = factor(
        x = c("01/01/2018 00:00:00", "01/06/2018 00:00:00", "05/01/2018 00:00:00"),
        levels = c("01/01/2018 00:00:00", "01/06/2018 00:00:00", "05/01/2018 00:00:00")
    ),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
sapply(df, class)
#>        col1        col2        col3        col4 
#>   "numeric" "character"    "factor"    "factor"
df
#>   col1 col2                col3                col4
#> 1    1    a 01/01/2017 00:00:00 01/01/2018 00:00:00
#> 2    2    b 01/06/2017 00:00:00 01/06/2018 00:00:00
#> 3    3    c 05/01/2017 00:00:00 05/01/2018 00:00:00
GetDateFromFactorLevels(df)
sapply(df, class)
#>        col1        col2        col3        col4 
#>   "numeric" "character"      "Date"      "Date"
df
#>   col1 col2       col3       col4
#> 1    1    a 2017-01-01 2018-01-01
#> 2    2    b 2017-06-01 2018-06-01
#> 3    3    c 2017-01-05 2018-01-05
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Look at the [RcppExamples](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppExamples) package and [source repository](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppexamples) which has

- a [Date (and Datetime) example](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppexamples/blob/master/src/DateExample.cpp)
- a [DataFrame example](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppexamples/blob/master/src/DataFrameExample.cpp)

You may in fact get by just changing the class attribute using the vector member function `attr()`.  But the simple way of constructing new vectors should work too.

Comment: The problem is that I want the values in `attr("levels")`. If I change the class of the `tempVec` vector I get `col3 =  c("1970-01-02", "1970-01-03", "1970-01-04")` with class `"Date"`.

Comment: Well even in R you'd go via `as.character()` first.  No magic bullets.  Or maybe you decide to treat your _existing_ `factor` as a hash map -- the 1,2,3,... are in fact lookups into your factor labels. Maybe use that?